# Stop scipy.optimize.minimize after maximum runtime

Tags: python, scipy, runtime, minimize

I run `scipy.optimize.minimize(method='L-BFGS-B')` on a cluster. Tasks running longer than 72 hours will be killed without any option of saving the result. Is there a way to exit `scipy.optimize.minimize()` after a runtime of T=48h has passed?

Comment: There is a `callback` method that you can use. Note that you can only stop after finishing one full iteration step. If your function value evaluation or your gradient is very costly you have to account for that.

Comment: Or, only allow a "small" number of iterations, save that result, than restart with the returned value. Is the problem large, or complex, or both?

Comment: The problem is large (100 to 1000 independent variables) and complex. I could indeed restart after a small number of iterations. It however also has its drawbacks, as the BFGS algorithm uses information from previous iterations, which then wont be more than 10. I do not see how I can stop the optimization with the callback function. I only managed to raise an error. can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

1. One approach is to estimate the evaluation time of one iteration and then set `maxiter` in the `options` argument accordingly.
2. Another approach is to define a class, which modifies a function `fun` such that it returns an error after a specified time and records the last input value `x` and its output `fun(x)`:

   ```
   from scipy.optimize import minimize
   import numpy as np
   import time

   class TimedFun:
       def __init__(self, fun, stop_after=10):
           self.fun_in = fun
           self.started = False
           self.stop_after = stop_after

       def fun(self, x):
           if self.started is False:
               self.started = time.time()
           elif abs(time.time() - self.started) >= self.stop_after:
               raise ValueError("Time is over.")
           self.fun_value = self.fun_in(x)
           self.x = x
           return self.fun_value
   ```

   With that the optimization can be stopped after `fun` is called, say, later than 2 seconds after the first call:

   ```
   ## Objective function:
   def fun(x):
       time.sleep(5)
       return sum(x**2)

   ## Minimize with early stopping:
   fun_timed = TimedFun(fun=fun, stop_after=2)
   try:
       minimize(fun=fun_timed.fun, x0=np.array([100]), method='L-BFGS-B')
   except Exception as e:
       print("Error: " + str(e))
   # Error: Time is over.

   ## Retrieve last evaluated `x` and `fun(x)`:
   print('x=', fun_timed.x, ', fun(x)=', fun_timed.fun_value, sep='')
   # x=[100.], fun(x)=10000.0
   ```

BTW, checkout my package [optimparallel](https://pypi.org/project/optimparallel), which allows you to speedup the optimization with parallel computing and to return the evaluated value `x`, `fun(x)`, and `jac(x)` of every step.

```
from optimparallel import minimize_parallel
minimize_parallel(fun=fun, x0=np.array([100]), parallel={'loginfo': True})
#      fun: 2.565413976271745e-17
# hess_inv: array([[0.50000039]])
#      jac: array([-1.29983171e-10])
#  loginfo: {'x': array([[ 1.00000000e+02],
#       [ 9.90000000e+01],
#       [ 9.50000000e+01],
#       [ 7.90000000e+01],
#       [ 8.22875951e-05],
#       [-5.06499159e-09]]), 'fun': array([[1.00000000e+04],
#       [9.80100000e+03],
#       [9.02500000e+03],
#       [6.24100000e+03],
#       [6.77124832e-09],
#       [2.56541398e-17]]), 'jac': array([[ 1.99999886e+02],
#       [ 1.97999907e+02],
#       [ 1.89999810e+02],
#       [ 1.57999875e+02],
#       [ 1.64585190e-04],
#       [-1.29983171e-10]])}
#  message: b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
#     nfev: 6
#      nit: 3
#   status: 0
#  success: True
#        x: array([-5.06499159e-09])
```